# What punctuation, if any, belongs between "says" and "Kevin"?

Tags: punctuation

> My Mom kinda chuckles and **says** “Kevin, that’s because you’re using adrenaline to run away from the…creature.”

Should I put punctuation after "says"?

Answer (score 1):

You should always put a comma between words like ‘says’ and a direct speech in apostrophes.

[Read up more about the use of punctuation in direct speech here.](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/punctuation/punctuation-in-direct-speech)

Comment: Daniel, thanks for helping me! So if I'm understanding you then I would also use a comma in this sentence after "says", correct?  "Nick looks over at Pete, and says "Hey, how are you?"

Comment: Yes. The correct sentence should be “Nick looks over at Pete and says, “Hey, how are you?””

Comment: Alright, I'm learning! I find learning English very difficult yet very satisfying. Would it be appropriate to ask you for help on a different topic while I have you here? I am having trouble with narration and could not find a "Narration or Narrative" option under posting questions. Is the character narration in the appropriate spot in the last sentence after “Janet:”? The conversation is: Ralph: “How are you?”
Janet: “I’m fine, Ralph.”
Ralph: “Anything new been going on?”
Janet: Janet starts laughing, “Yeah, I fell off the back porch again.”

Comment: Yes, that should be correct.